# Extend the php file's data

Tags: php

I have a `test01.php`:

```
<?php

$_LANG['a'] = "A";
$_LANG['b'] = "B";
$_LANG['c'] = "C";

// I want to add the `addon/test01_addon.php`'s data to there

print_r($_LANG);
```

and I also have the `addon/test01_addon.php` for `test01.php`:

```
<?php

$_LANG['c'] = 'C';
$_LANG['d'] = 'D';
```

I have this requirement for extends the `test01.php`'s `$_LANG`'s data.

how can I join the `test01_addon.php`'s data to `test01.php`?

Comment: include test01_addon.php in test01.php

Comment: In addition to this, is there other functions for doing this?

Comment: You can try with session

Answer (score 1):

Just use `include` or `require`:

```
$_LANG['a'] = "A";
$_LANG['b'] = "B";
$_LANG['c'] = "C";


include_once('addon/test01_addon.php');

print_r($_LANG);
```